# Divide integer in array and store it as double in array

Tags: c++, divide

```
for(int i = 0; i < iData; i++)
{
    if(hPred[i]<=jData[i])
    {
        akur[i] = hPred[i] / jData[i];
    }
    else if(hPred[i]>jData[i])
    {
        akur[i] = hPred[i] / jData[i];
        akur[i] = akur[i] - 1.000;
    }
}
```

I got some issues here. I wanted to divide data in hPred[] with jData[] and store it in an array as double(akur[]). Instead, I got this:

[image: jData[]]

[image: hPred[] and the result(akur[])]

[image: RESULT]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? What's the expected output?

Comment: Why we need "else if" case here? What is the data type for your array? And please provide textual output as text and not as an image on any external servers. Links may be gone in the future...

Comment: I want to count the accuracy of data (it's a prediction)

Comment: Can you please stop adding pictures here!

Comment: As long as we do not know the numbers in hPred and jData we can't know the result of a division?! Maybe you give us a complete sample of your function/method! inlcuding some sample data.

Comment: typecast any operand to float while division, eg :  akur[i] = (float)hPred[i] / jData[i];

Comment: Your problem is you first do integer division and then cast the result to double. That's not going to add any decimal values to the result. You should expand the question to include all the variables' declarations.

Comment: Sorry, I can't respond as quickly as possible. I'm studying in a boarding school, which restricts its students from using pc/electronic devices. I can only respond in an uncertain time. But now, I just resolved the problems, Thanks :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < iData; i++){
    if(hPred[i]<=jData[i]){
        akur[i] = (float)hPred[i] / jData[i];
    }else if(hPred[i]>jData[i]){
        akur[i] = (float)hPred[i] / jData[i];
        akur[i] = akur[i] - 1.000;
    }
}
```

typecast any operand to float before division